# How to hide every other option field in a select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to hide every `":nth-child(even)"` of the options fields.
I have spent hours to find the answer, but can't find it.

Is that possible with CSS or jQuery?

```
<select name="testbox" id="testbox_id">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $('#testbox_id option:nth-child(even)').hide()

Answer (score 1):

You can set *display* property to *none* for `#testbox_id option:nth-child(even)`

```css
#testbox_id option:nth-child(even){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="testbox" id="testbox_id">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
</select>
```